# Shnayim Veshishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred sixty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yered was 162 years old when his son Chanoch was born.